# On android, how to abort geocoder.getFromLocation

Tags: android, multithreading, location, google-play-services

A am using the code bellow to get the adress of my lat/lon

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

The method getFromLocation is bloking. I am already execution in another Thread, but i would like to cancel the operation.

So how do i cancel the getFromLocation ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Android documentation for [Displaying a Location Address](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html).

Here you create an IntentService, which runs on a worker thread and finishes itself after the `onHandleIntent()` has completed. They are using a [ResultReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html#ResultReceiver(android.os.Handler)), that receives the results from geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1). The `handler` passed into the `ResultReceiver` constructor, would be back on the main/ui thread.

In this example, you wouldn't need to cancel the operation at all. It is running in a service, on a worker thread and therefore not blocking your main/ui thread. Also, the service shuts itself down after it completes geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1). If you no longer wanted to receive the Location results back on the main/ui thread, you could easily handle that as well from within the `ResultReceiver`.